# C# localization online

Tags: c#

I have a C# app which I want to internationalize, I want the users to be able to edit resource files on the internet. Is there a way to collaboratively change the C# resource files on the internet ?
I know there are open source PHP projects for android which let users translate xml string files online, looking for something similar for C# which is free and open source

EDIT:
I have given a try to transifex, it does good job to list down all the strings in the .resx files which are manualy created and contain strings only.
However it worked out that it is not very intelligent and useful for localizing forms. Uploading forms resources to transifex causes all the irrelevant information being populated for translations.
Like all the x, y location of my controls in the form and even stuff like System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 . 
In mycase I had only a couple of strings in the form for button names and labels, but transifex showed like 100s of irrelevant things along with it.
So makes it quite useless for C# forms translations if your forms have been designed with the VS designer.
Translators are not necessarily programmers showing them all the unnecessary fields is a big mess..

Comment: So you want the website not only to allow work on translations, but also to determine which strings in your files are relevant and which not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/).

It's a web plattform for managing translations collaboratively. They also support [Windows ressource files](http://help.transifex.com/features/formats.html#resx-files).

Hosting is free for open source projects, and the software itself is [open source](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transifex/).

Comment: Hosting is free for open source projects, and the software itself is open source.

Comment: Thanks, but my project is not open source which means I cant use this option. Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: @Ahmed Transifex itself is open source, so you can just download it and host it yourself.

Comment: Given a try to it, works good for manually created resx files but not quite good with designer generated forms resx file. I have upated in my question..